# How does one decide the final clusters when using the means shift algorthm?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I am reading a bit about the means shift clustering algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift) and this is what i got so far. For each point in your data set : select all points within a certain distance of it (including the original point), calculate the mean for all these points, repeat until these means stabilize.

What I'm confused about is how does one go from here in deciding what the final clusters are , and on what conditions do these means merge. Also, does the distance used to select the points fluctuate through the iterations or does it remain constant?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean shift cluster finding is a simple iterative process which is actually guaranteed to converge. The iteration starts from a starting point *x*, and the iteration steps are (note that *x* may have several components, as the algorithm will work in higher dimensions, as well):

- calculate the weighted mean position *x'* of all points around *x* - maybe the simplest form is to calculate the average of positions of all points within *d* distance from x, but the gaussian function is also commonly used and mathematically beneficial.
- set *x* <- *x'*
- repeat until the difference between *x* and *x'* is very small

This can be used in cluster analysis by starting with different values of *x*. The final values will end up at different cluster centers. The number of clusters cannot be known (other than it is <= number of points).

The upper level algorithm is:

- go through a selection of starting values
- for each value, calculate the convergence value as shown above
- if the value is not already in the list of convergence values, add it to the list (allow some reasonable tolerance for numerical imprecision)

And then you have the list of clusters. The only difficult thing is finding a reasonable selection of starting values. It is easy with one or two dimensions, but with higher dimensionalities exhaustive searches are not quite possible.

All starting points, which end up into the same mode (point of convergence) belong to the same cluster.

It may be of interest that if you are doing this on a 2D image, it should be sufficient to calculate the gradient (i.e. the first iteration) for each pixel. This is a fast operation with common convolution techniques, and then it is relatively easy to group the pixels into clusters.

Comment: This answers the "when do i stop?" question but it does not answer the "when are 2 centroids considered the same?" . Considering the algorithm specifies that we repeat the step for each point and we end up with an unknown number of clusters, I have to ask then:  is a final cluster considered the set of all points contained inside centroids that intersect each-other ? I hope this makes sense

Comment: @omu_negru: Two centroids are the same if they are at the same position. Of course, there has to be some tolerance for the calculation imprecision.That is the phase where the value is either added or not added to the list. A point belongs to a cluster, if the algorithm started from that point ends up into its centroid. The final clusters are represented by the list of centroids, and for each centroid a list of points belonging to that cluster.